# AssertionError: Index is not unique on dataframe (Entity cust) using Featuretools

Tags: python, python-3.x, feature-extraction, featuretools

I have a dataframe as below

```
customerid                                   term   age
08a858899538ddb8e015390510b321f0830199897     30     24
18a858959537a097401537a4e316e25f730196361     60     72
a8589c253ace09b0153af6ba58f1f313019822366     45     38
```

I am creating an entity as below using **featuretools**

```
es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id = 'cust', dataframe = df, index = 'customerid')
```

but i get the error

```
AssertionError: Index is not unique on dataframe (Entity cust)
```

yet customerid is the identifier

Comment: Is it possible that `customerid` is not unique? You can check if that is the case with `len(es) == es.customerid.nunique()` (if it's False, then you have repeated customerids).

Comment: @JulianPeller is right. You should run that check on the dataframe not the entityset though, so the code would be `len(df) == df.customerid.nunique()`

Comment: Oh, you are right. My mistake.

Comment: This error also pops up when there is no ID to begin with in the first place. In these cases, passing an arbitrary index value with ```index='...'``` and ```make_index=True``` is the solution.